# Why I am getting this uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error in Jquery while making a get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am using a very simple code just to learn how to make 'GET' requests in AJAX, but can't get rid of this error though the data seems to be retrieved from the javascript file anyway. Any suggestions ?

Here's my trivial code for html and js

```js
$.get('JsonData.js', function (data, textStatus) {
    $('p').append(data);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

And this is how JsonData.js file looks like :

```
{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};
```

and finally here's is the error :

> VM190:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>       at DOMEval (jquery.js:111)
>       at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:345)
>       at text script (jquery.js:9640)
>       at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8787)
>       at done (jquery.js:9255)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.js:9548)

Comment: Are you actually using `$.get`? Or are you using `$.getJSON` or even `$.getScript`? Each is going to make a request but they will be handled differently. Also as a side note that isn't valid JSON syntax (keys need quotes for example).

Comment: Why append the `;`?

Comment: Try changing the file to proper JSON:  {"name":"John","age":31,"city":"New York"}

Comment: Even though the semi colon is not needed, the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/7L2kczyq/ - plus, if it's supposed to be JSON, then it should look like this: `{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}`

Comment: Decide whether you want an executable JavaScript code, or a JSON data structure. Then name your file accordingly, fix the content, and give them the right content-type header.

Comment: The error hasn't gone even when I changed the structure of JS object in the JsonData.js file. Any other solutions ? Please help me with this because I need to use AJAX request several times in my project and I want it to look clean.